# Why doesn't my React onChange method match my arrow function in enzymes containsAllMatchingElements test

Tags: reactjs, testing, chai, enzyme, arrow-functions

I have written a test case which is trying to test if react is rendering all my elements correctly.

Code that is being tested:

```
...
eventDateChange(moment, dateType) {
    const {handleEventChange} = this.props;
    let {event} = this.state;
    event[dateType] = moment.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    this.setState({event});
    handleEventChange(event);
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="event-input">
            <DateTime
                onChange={moment => this.eventDateChange(moment,'startDate')}
                inputProps={{placeholder: 'From:'}}
                dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
        </div>
    )
}
...
```

Test code:

```
import React from "react";
import {expect} from "chai";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import EventInput from "../../../blog/event/EventInput.jsx";
import DateTime from "react-datetime";


describe('EventInput', () => {
        it('is rendering an calendar icon', () => {
            const wrapper = shallow(<EventInput/>);
            expect(wrapper.containsAllMatchingElements([
                <DateTime
                    onChange={moment => wrapper.instance.eventDateChange(moment,'startDate')}
                    inputProps={{placeholder: 'From:'}}
                    dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
            ])).to.equal(true);
        });
    });
```

The problem is that my onChange method is failing the tests. If I remove the onChange method from the code and the test, the test is succeeding.

As you can see I was using Mocha, Chai, Enzyme in the tests.

From what I can see all the props are the same except for the onChange where I can't use this in the test and need to change it to the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of how enzyme compares nodes (https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/d34630e9c3e07ca7983d37695d5668377f94a793/src/Utils.js#L102), it looks like enzyme requires props of type "function" to exactly match when doing this comparison (`right[prop] === left[prop]`) and will return false if this condition is not met.

Your lambda functions are not identical, so the `===` comparison will fail. Whenever you use lambda, you are creating a new anonymous function, so even if the parameters and body are the same between two lambda declarations, they are actually two separate function instances.

To get around this problem, you could either 1) create a reference to the exact function instance used in your component so that your test can reference it, or 2) use a different enzyme API here. I would suggest #2. It seems like you are overtesting a bit by checking all property values, and you could use something like this instead:

```js
it('is rendering an calendar icon', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<EventInput/>);
    expect(wrapper.matchesElement(
        <div>
            <DateTime />
        </div>
    )).to.equal(true);
});
```

If you want to test individual props on the DateTime, you could additionally do something like: `expect(wrapper.find("DateTime").props().dateFormat).to.equal("YYYY-MM-DD")`.

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer!
nice explaining the reasons of the comparison as well.